# How to move Navbar Elements to the center?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to move 'Try again' between 'New Colors' and 'Easy' to the center. I already tried using flex and other things but I can't figure it out. I want to make it responsive as well.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-md-5 pl-md-5">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#"
            >NEW COLORS <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a
          >
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="navbar-nav d-flex">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#"
            >Try Again <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a
          >
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto pr-md-5 mr-md-5">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#"
            >EASY <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a
          >
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">HARD</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: hi, please attach css, which you already tried to apply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in `d-flex` and `justify-content-between` class in `id="navbarSupportedContent" <div>`. Then remove `ml-auto` class in the last `navbar-nav <ul>`. Then, the nav item will be align left, center and right.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse d-flex justify-content-between" id="navbarSupportedContent">
     ...
<ul class="navbar-nav pr-md-5 mr-md-5"> <!-- Remove ml-auto -->
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light">
  <div class='container'>
    <!-- Add in d-flex and justify-content-between -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse d-flex justify-content-between" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-md-5 pl-md-5">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">NEW COLORS <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="navbar-nav"> <!-- Remove d-flex -->
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Try Again <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="navbar-nav pr-md-5 mr-md-5"> <!-- Remove ml-auto -->
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">EASY <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">HARD</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
</div>
```